# 404 - Request resource is not available - Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I'm trying to use Spring framework in my webapplication but I'm having troubles while trying to set it up. I know a lot of people has asked something similiar to my question, but I couldn't have my problem solved with all the hints I've seen.

Please refer below for my code which tries to open an `.html` file using Spring framework.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


</web-app>
```

servlet-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pluralsight.controller"/>

<!--  
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
-->

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB INF/jsp" p:suffix=".jsp">

</bean>
</beans>
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<H4>Welcome</H4>
</body>
</html>
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

addMinutes.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Minutes Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Minutes Exercised</h1>
    <form:form command name="exercise">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Minutes Exercise Today</td>
                <td><form:input path="minutes"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Enter Exercise"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

`HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet fitTrackerServlet threw exception
type Exception report`

message
`Servlet.init() for servlet fitTrackerServlet threw exception`

description
`The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.`

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet fitTrackerServlet threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0.41
I am using `localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/addMinutes.html`
I am not able to open html pages.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: show us your `fitTrackerServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing Java code it's hard to tell if it is a main reason, but you have a missing dash here:

```
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB INF/jsp/"></property>
```

I assume you use standard naming conventions, co it should be `WEB-INF` instead of `WEB INF`:

```
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
```